# Валидация данных в Symfony 3?

Tags: symfony, symfony3

Есть Symfony 3.4.

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Matches /login exactly
     *
     * @Route("/login", name="login")
     *
     * @param Request $request
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function loginAction(Request $request)
    {
        $email = $request->query->get('email');

        $password = $request->query->get('password');

        if (empty($email) || empty($password)) {
            return new Response(
                'Email or password can not be blank',
                Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED,
                ['Content-type' => 'application/json',]
            );
        }

        /** @var EncoderFactory $factory */
        $factory = $this->get('security.encoder_factory');

        /** @var UserManager $user_manager */
        $user_manager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');

        /** @var User $user */
        $user = $user_manager->findUserByEmail($email);

        if (!$user) {
            return new Response(
                'Email doesnt exists',
                Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED,
                ['Content-type' => 'application/json',]
            );
        }

        $encoder = $factory->getEncoder($user);

        $salt = $user->getSalt();

        if (!$encoder->isPasswordValid($user->getPassword(), $password, $salt)) {
            return new Response(
                'Email or Password not valid.',
                Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED,
                ['Content-type' => 'application/json',]
            );
        }

        $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'main', $user->getRoles());

        $this->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);

        $this->get('session')->set('_security_main', serialize($token));

        $event = new InteractiveLoginEvent($request, $token);

        $this->get("event_dispatcher")->dispatch("security.interactive_login", $event);

        return new Response(
            'Welcome '. $user->getUsername(),
            Response::HTTP_OK,
            ['Content-type' => 'application/json']
        );
    }
}
```

С помощью POSTman отправляю POST запрс паролем и email. Всё работает, но подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать валидацию приходящих email и пароля?

Comment: Почему вы не используете внедрение зависимостей? И зачем строить велосипеды с валидацией, если всё это уже есть во фреймворке https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html

Comment: @AntonKucenko, спасибо, а для этого нужно создавать форму?

Comment: [Пример](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/security/form_login_setup.html) стандартной формы. Если нужно хранить пользователей с ДБ, то нужно подключать [FOSUserBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html)

Comment: Если хотите просто проверить e-mail, не заморачиваясь с формами, то `filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)`, пароль у вас итак валидируется в коде `isPasswordValid`. Непонятен смысл такой валидации при логине. email - у вас это ключ. При невалидном емейле юзер и не найдется.